# Android Lollipop not changing RatingBar color

Tags: android

I want to change a color of ratingBar, so I wrote a style for it but on Android Lollipop is not working. 
I used all the available options, how to fix it?

```
    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rating="@{comment.rating}"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small_2dp"
        style="@style/RatingBar"
        tools:rating="5"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />

<style name="RatingBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar.Small">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/grullo</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">@color/goldenyellow</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/goldenyellow</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/goldenyellow</item>
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/goldenyellow</item>
    <item name="android:secondaryProgressTint">@color/goldenyellow</item>
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/goldenyellow</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use your rating bar in xml like this :

```
 <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:rating="@{comment.rating}"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_small_2dp"
        android:theme="@style/RatingBar"
        tools:rating="5"
        android:isIndicator="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView11" />
```